# How can I improve this characters conversion script?

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression, unicode

I'm using the code below to convert characters like '\u00c0' to Unicode format like 'À'

`unicode(){ sed -i 's/\\\u00c0/À/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00c1/Á/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00c2/Â/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00c3/Ã/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00c4/Ä/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00c5/Å/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00c6/Æ/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00c7/Ç/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00c8/È/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00c9/É/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00ca/Ê/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00cb/Ë/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00cc/Ì/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00cd/Í/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00ce/Î/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00cf/Ï/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00d0/Ð/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00d1/Ñ/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00d2/Ò/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00d3/Ó/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00d4/Ô/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00d5/Õ/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00d6/Ö/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00d7/×/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00d8/Ø/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00d9/Ù/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00da/Ú/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00db/Û/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00dc/Ü/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00dd/Ý/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00de/Þ/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00df/ß/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00e0/à/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00e1/á/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00e2/â/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00e3/ã/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00e4/ä/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00e5/å/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00e6/æ/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00e7/ç/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00e8/è/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00e9/é/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00ea/ê/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00eb/ë/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00ec/ì/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00ed/í/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00ee/î/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00ef/ï/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00f0/ð/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00f1/ñ/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00f2/ò/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00f3/ó/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00f4/ô/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00f5/õ/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00f6/ö/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00f7/÷/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00f8/ø/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00f9/ù/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00fa/ú/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00fb/û/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00fc/ü/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00fd/ý/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00fe/þ/g' $1;sed -i 's/\\\u00ff/ÿ/g' $1; }`

Then I use `unicode file.txt` to convert to Unicode.

If I have a file called original_text and it has a string like \u00d8rsted, for example, run `unicode original_text` will convert that string to `Ørsted`.

This is working very well but the code seems to be pretty incorrect and actually it looks a bit ugly.

I wonder, is there a better way to do such conversion (on shell or even a unix command to convert such characters.)?

Comment: Good start; only 999,936 commands to go.  Seriously, (1) You shouldn’t run so many separate `sed` commands.  You can do `sed -i -e 's/\\\u00c0/À/g' -e 's/\\\u00c1/Á/g' … -e 's/\\\u00ff/ÿ/g' "$1"`.  (2) As indicated above, you should quote all shell variables (e.g., `"$1"`) unless you have a good reason not to and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  (3) I’m not sure what it is, but I’m 99% sure that there’s a better way to do this — maybe in Perl, Python or C.

Comment: I'll try to remember it when I use sed again. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ascii2uni` from [uni2ascii](http://billposer.org/Software/uni2ascii.html) can do that.

```
$ ./ascii2uni -q -a U <<< '\u00d8rsted'
Ørsted
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is better than I could expect!